# What is the traditional accompaniment for Duck Confit?

Tags: duck, confit

I have a few duck legs that I made a confit from earlier this week. I'm thinking of serving them with Parmesan Dauphinoise and some beans from the garden tonight. I was wonderring though, what would be the traditional accompaniment for duck confit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In southwest of France, we serve confit with "pommes sarladaises", which are more or less fries cooked in duck fat in a pan. There is also garlic and parsley.

You can use confit in "cassoulet" as well. This is something like chili con carne with white beans instead of red ones, onion, carrot, tomato, garlic (and many other secrets which change from home to home).

EDIT: A variant of "pommes de terre sarladaises" includes mushrooms, in particular "cèpes" ([Boletus edulis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boletus_edulis)) together with potatoes.

Comment: I saw on the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_confit) that _pommes de terre à la sarladaise_ was the traditional accompaniment, but having never been to France I couldn't be sure. It's good to have it confirmed by an actual Frenchman.

Answer (score 1):

Purple Cabbage.

I fry it with onions, balsamic, and something to sweeten it a bit. (Maple Syrup, Honey, Red Currant Jam). Goes nicely with duck.

also consider an Onion Marmalade.

Answer (score 1):

When I've eaten it in south west France it's almost always with parboiled potatoes 'roughed up' by shaking in a pan with the lid on with some crushed garlic, then roast in the oven in the duck fat from the tin and served with French beans.

So I'd say you are not a million miles away from it, especially as the other times have been with douphinoise.

Answer (score 1):

A complement of duck is apple sauce, or sage and onion.

Answer (score 0):

Duck does of course have a traditional (albeit perhaps no longer mainstream) place in European cuisine, for which there are many different ways of severing it. However, if you're a fan of Chinese cuisine I highly recommend trying [**plum sauce**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plum_sauce) as an accompaniment. This is a traditional and common way of serving (crispy) duck Chinese-style - not least in take-aways! If you're feeling bold, you may even want to try [making it yourself](http://www.cooks.com/rec/view/0,1755,128188-248196,00.html).